# What is the limiting transition matrix of a general Markov Chain?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

For the case of an ergodic Markov Chain, or a random walk on a strongly connected graph, the limiting transition matrix is a matrix with each rows equal to the stationary distribution of the Markov Chain (the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue 1). This can be easily understood since the random walk will have explored the entire graph and reached equilibrium.

If I have an non-ergodic Markov Chain on $N$ states (let's say that it is also aperiodic), or a random walk on a non strongly connected graph, defined by a transition matrix $P$, how can I find the limiting transition matrix $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P^n$ if it exists?

I think that one would have to find all the strongly connected components and build the corresponding condensation graph. For each strongly connected component that is a leaf of the condensation graph we can computed its stationary distribution. The limiting transition matrix should be a combination of the different stationary distributions (on the rows). But how can one build this combination? How to choose the weight each stationary distributions?

Comment: Never mind, my answer doesn't work. (It forgets about generalized eigenvectors, which are doing most of the work in this case.)

Comment: Thanks @MishaLavrov for trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a way to solve my problem.

The rows of the limiting transition matrix are linear combinations of the stationary distributions, $\pi_k$, $k=1,...,K$ of the $K$ strongly connected components that correspond to a leaf of the condensation graph (i.e. the absorbing states).

The coefficients associated with each $\pi_k$ for each row are given by the matrix $B=NR$, where the entry $(i,j)$ gives the probability of being absorbed in the absorbing state $j$ when starting from transient state $i$.

Here, $N=(I-Q)^{-1}$ is the [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix) of the absorbing Markov Chain, $Q$ gives the probability to transition from transient states to transient state and $R$ gives the probability to transition from transient states to absorbing states. They are found by rearranging the transition matrix as

$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 Q & R\\
 \mathbf{0} & I_r
\end{array}
\right).$$